# Factory method doesn't meet the DRY principle

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using [Proto.Actor](https://proto.actor/) and I have an actor which acts as a proxy and forwards the messages to the appropriate exchange just because each exchange has different subscription methods, different parameters are passed, etc. I made a factory method which looks like below. What I don't like is the fact that there is a repeated logic. What would you recommend to me in order to follow up the DRY principle (Do not repeat yourself)?

```cs
using Proto;

namespace Api.Actors.Exchanges;

internal sealed class ExchangeFactory
{
    private readonly IContext _context;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly int _retryAttempts;

    internal ExchangeFactory(IContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int retryAttempts)
    {
        _context = context;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _retryAttempts = retryAttempts;
    }

    internal PID CreateExchange(string exchange, string accountId)
    {
        switch (exchange)
        {
            case "ftx":
                var exchangeProps = Props.FromProducer(() =>
                        // ActivatorUtilities is used for partial dependency injection.
                        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<FtxSubscription>(_serviceProvider, accountId)
                    )
                    .WithChildSupervisorStrategy(
                        new OneForOneStrategy((_, _) => SupervisorDirective.Restart, _retryAttempts, null)
                    );
                return _context.SpawnNamed(exchangeProps, $"{exchange}:{accountId}");

            case "kraken":
                var exchangeProps2 = Props.FromProducer(() =>
                        // ActivatorUtilities is used for partial dependency injection.
                        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<KrakenSubscription>(_serviceProvider, accountId)
                    )
                    .WithChildSupervisorStrategy(
                        new OneForOneStrategy((_, _) => SupervisorDirective.Restart, _retryAttempts, null)
                    );
                return _context.SpawnNamed(exchangeProps2, $"{exchange}:{accountId}");

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know C#, so my answer is pretty generic. The only difference between the two cases is within the closure / lambda (or whatever C# calls it), so you can just assign the respective closure within the switch cases and call the common code afterwards.

**Pseudo code**:

```
using Proto;

namespace Api.Actors.Exchanges;

internal sealed class ExchangeFactory
{
    private readonly IContext _context;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly int _retryAttempts;

    internal ExchangeFactory(IContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int retryAttempts)
    {
        _context = context;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _retryAttempts = retryAttempts;
    }

    internal PID CreateExchange(string exchange, string accountId)
    {
        var producer;

        switch (exchange)
        {
            case "ftx":
                producer = () => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<FtxSubscription>(_serviceProvider, accountId);
                break;

            case "kraken":
                producer = () => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<KrakenSubscription>(_serviceProvider, accountId);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        var exchangeProps = Props.FromProducer(producer)
            .WithChildSupervisorStrategy(
                new OneForOneStrategy((_, _) => SupervisorDirective.Restart, _retryAttempts, null)
            );
        return _context.SpawnNamed(exchangeProps, $"{exchange}:{accountId}");
    }
}
```

or, even better, just store the varying type:

```
using Proto;

namespace Api.Actors.Exchanges;

internal sealed class ExchangeFactory
{
    private readonly IContext _context;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly int _retryAttempts;

    internal ExchangeFactory(IContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int retryAttempts)
    {
        _context = context;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _retryAttempts = retryAttempts;
    }

    internal PID CreateExchange(string exchange, string accountId)
    {
        var subscription_type;

        switch (exchange)
        {
            case "ftx":
                subscription_type = FtxSubscription;
                break;

            case "kraken":
                subscription_type = KrakenSubscription;
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        var exchangeProps = Props.FromProducer(
            () => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<subscription_type>(_serviceProvider, accountId)
        )
            .WithChildSupervisorStrategy(
                new OneForOneStrategy((_, _) => SupervisorDirective.Restart, _retryAttempts, null)
            );
        return _context.SpawnNamed(exchangeProps, $"{exchange}:{accountId}");
    }
}
```

However, I don't know if this is possible in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much! small syntax improvement https://pastebin.com/bTaMeAnF

Comment: Please fix your second code example because that always creates the same type: CreateInstance<FtxSubscription>

Comment: @nop Your pastebin code still has code duplication inside the switch expression which could be eliminated.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I believe it is fine because I'm using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>` for partial dependency injection. FtxSubscription, KrakenSubscription might have different injected parameters. I mean in terms of constructor parameters they are not always the same.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you. Done. It was probably too late yesterday. ;)

Comment: @RichardNeumann Unfortunately this does not work in C#. The generic type parameter must be compile-time resolvable.

Comment: @PeterCsala I feared as much, hence my caveat, that I don't know C#.

Answer (score 3):

You might implement a generic version of your method because your cases only differ in a generic argument of `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`

```
PID CreateExchange<T>(string accountId)
{
                var exchangeProps = Props.FromProducer(() =>
                    // ActivatorUtilities is used for partial dependency injection.
                    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(_serviceProvider, accountId)
                )
                .WithChildSupervisorStrategy(
                    new OneForOneStrategy((_, _) => SupervisorDirective.Restart, _retryAttempts, null)
                );
                return _context.SpawnNamed(exchangeProps, $"{exchange}:{accountId}");
}
```

Then your string driven version is just this:

```
PID CreateExchange(string exchange, string accountId)
{
        switch (exchange)
        {
            case "ftx":
                return this.CreateExchange<FtxSubscription>(accountId);

            case "kraken":
                return this.CreateExchange<KrakenSubscription>(accountId);

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
}
```